# Push to private docker registry using mac

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Mac Os

```
Sierra 10.12.5
```

Docker on mac

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:31:53 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:51:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Registry

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:20:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:21:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

So I have setup a secure registry using certificates...

```
https://my-registry:5000/v2/_catalog
```

returns

```
{"repositories":[]}
```

But when I try through the mac docker, I get...

```
docker push docker-registry-dev-0:5000/impact-twilio-proxy
The push refers to a repository [my-registry:5000/xxxxxx]
Get https://my-registry:5000/v2/: dial tcp xxx.xxx.xxx.27:5000: getsockopt: no route to host
```

Where do I put the self signed certificate of the registry on the mac client? But this doesn't seem like certificate error...

The command I used to run the registry...

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000  -v $(pwd)/registry-certs:/certs  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/my-registry.cert  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/my-registry.key --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Comment: This is the standard v2 registry docker provides, right?

Comment: Yep. I added the command I ran to run it...

Comment: As far as I remember.. you need to put the ca on every docker host that is using it. You don't need the ca on your client because you client is just instructing docker daemon what to do.  https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/#using-self-signed-certificates

Comment: Im on vpn it may be the issue...

Comment: The "no route to host" part I'm not sure about. Is to actually a name in dns or just something hacked into a local hosts file?

Comment: It is an actual dns. The registry is running on Centos VM on Openstack. Bit I can ping and everything...

Comment: ah right. So you are using your docker daemon on mac to pull from a registry with self signed cert. That means the docker daemon on your mac needs to know about this certificate. Seems this was discussed here : https://forums.docker.com/t/adding-self-signed-certificates/9761 (slightly awkward)

Comment: Actually two problems. 1- Resolved the no route to host. The bridge network on my mac is conflicting. Foumd a githib issue about this... Now I'm getting cert error. I will update my question later...

Comment: It might be less hassle to just use Let's Encrypt : https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#support-for-lets-encrypt

Comment: Possibly. But my issue was no route to host. Now getting signed by unknown authority

Comment: Ok so I resolved "The no route to host" issue. As for the certificate, since it is an internal private registry i'm setting it as insecure until I sort out a proper certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The no route to host was because my Mac docker bridge network was conflicting with my works VPN network. Simply forcing the bridge to another network worked...

See here: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25645